# Typoscript: How can I get the ID of the first child page of the current page?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I would like to have a link in my template to the first child page (it is a section overview page, so there will always be child pages available). The link will always have the same text.

How do I get the ID of the first child page?

```
pagelink = TEXT
pagelink {
    value = Link to first child page
    typolink {
        parameter = [[id of first child page]]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
pagelink = HMENU
pagelink {
    # only display if there is a subpage
    stdWrap.required = 1
    # with value directory, the default special.value is the current page id
    special = directory
    # limit to 1 page
    maxItems = 1
    # link item
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO = 1
    }
}
```

To override the page title, use this:

```
pageLink = HMENU
pageLink {
    # only display if there is a subpage
    stdWrap.required = 1
    # with value directory, the default special.value is the current page id
    special = directory
    # limit to 1 page
    maxItems = 1
    # link item
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO = 1
        NO {
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
            stdWrap.cObject {
                typolink.parameter.field = uid
                # override text of menu item
                value = Dummy Text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Gives me the correct link. Can you tell me how to replace the page title in the menu item? Or do I have to hide it with CSS and use a wrap to show the text I need?

Comment: @Tim Yes, i added this to my post.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it (e.g. using HMENU) but I would go for this one as it's clear and easy to modify if you once decide to make it more complex (e.g. have the page title somewhere in the text link, render thumbnail based on the media field).

```
pagelink = CONTENT
pagelink {
  table = pages
  select {
    pidInList = this
    orderBy = sorting ASC
    max = 1
  }
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    value = Link to first child page
    typolink {
      parameter.field = uid
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTES**

- To have the page title as the text link, replace `value = Link to first child page` with `field = title`
- It will display correct link only on that overview page, not on its subpages. To display it on the subpages a different approach would have to be taken.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this, because pages of invalid types (Sysfolder, Spacer) could also be linked. Also pages where "Hide in Menu" is set would be displayed.

Comment: @Shufla thanks for the note. Maybe I can add a `where` clause to the `select` to filter out hidden pages... `where = doktype=1 AND hidden=0`

Comment: @Tim Of course you can do that, but there are more values to be respected. HMENU does all that for you.

Comment: Well, I presumed specific page tree structure which wouldn't contain pages like sysfolder under those "section overview" pages. As you already mentioned, it can be made more robust with `where` clause.